# Xamarin ActivityIndicator Not Working

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having problems getting an Activity Indicator to display in my Xamarin.Forms application. I am using XAML with Code-behind and it is bound to a view model.

All the settings appear to my eye to be correct, and when I step through the code I can see the IsBusy property being set to True and False appropriately - but the actual ActivityIndicator does not display at all.

Can any see what I've got wrong?

**Login.Xaml.Cs**

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechsportiseApp.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using TechsportiseApp.API;
using TechsportiseApp.ViewModels;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TechsportiseApp.Views
{
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            var viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("New", "addperson.png", async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register());
            }));

        }

        public string CleanResponse(string reason)
        {
            var str = reason;
            var charsToRemove = new string[] { "[", "]", "{", "}", "\"" };
            foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
            {
                str = str.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

            return str;
        }

        async void OnLogin(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Validations here
            if (email.Text == "")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "You must enter an Email address", "OK");
                return;
            }
            else if (password.Text == "")
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "You must enter a Password", "OK");
                return;
            }
            //We are good to go
            else
            {
                this.IsBusy = true;
                string APIServer = Application.Current.Properties["APIServer"].ToString();
                var client = new RestClient(APIServer);
                var request = new RestRequest("api/account/sign-in", Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                request.AddJsonBody(new
                                        {
                                            email = email.Text,
                                            password = password.Text
                                        }
                                    );

                var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;

                this.IsBusy = false;
                //Valid response
                if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                {
                    var tokenobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(response.Content);
                    Application.Current.Properties["Token"] = tokenobject.Access_token;
                    string token = Application.Current.Properties["Token"].ToString();
                    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

                }
                //Error response
                else
                {
                    var statuscode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                    var content = response.Content;
                    var exception = response.ErrorException;
                    var error = response.ErrorMessage;
                    var statusdesc = response.StatusDescription;

                    await DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "Your login has failed. Please check your details and try again.", "OK");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Login.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TechsportiseApp.Views.Login">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                    Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                    WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                     Orientation="Vertical"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">

                        <ScrollView  Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                     Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Image Source = "splash.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" />          
                                <Label Text="Race Director"
                                FontAttributes="Bold"
                                FontSize="Large"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                <Label Text="by Techsportise"
                                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                                <BoxView HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                <Entry x:Name="email" Text="" Placeholder="Email address"/>
                                <Entry x:Name="password" Text="" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password"/>
                                <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Login" Clicked="OnLogin" Style="{StaticResource Buttons}"/>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ScrollView>
                </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" Padding="12"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">

                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color ="#80000000"/>

                <Label Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>

            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**LoginViewModel.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace TechsportiseApp.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private bool _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _isBusy; }
            set
            {
                if (_isBusy == value)
                    return;

                _isBusy = value;
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Worked with me:

```
private async void BtnLogin_OnClickedAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = true;
    await Task.Delay(1000); // This Line solved the problem with me
    await LoginMethod();
    activityIndicator.IsRunning = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't notifying the changes of `IsBusy` property.

Edited code:

**Login.Xaml.cs:**

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechsportiseApp.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using TechsportiseApp.API;
using TechsportiseApp.ViewModels;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TechsportiseApp.Views
{
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        public Login ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            var viewModel = new LoginViewModel();
            BindingContext = viewModel;
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("New", "addperson.png", async () =>
            {
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register());
            }));

        }

        public string CleanResponse(string reason)
        {
            var str = reason;
            var charsToRemove = new string[] { "[", "]", "{", "}", "\"" };
            foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
            {
                str = str.Replace(c, string.Empty);
            }

            return str;
        }
    }
}
```

**Login.Xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TechsportiseApp.Views.Login">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                    iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                    Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                    WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         Orientation="Vertical"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">
                <ScrollView  Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source = "splash.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" />          
                        <Label Text="Race Director"
                        FontAttributes="Bold"
                        FontSize="Large"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        <Label Text="by Techsportise"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                        <BoxView HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Entry x:Name="email" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email address"/>
                        <Entry x:Name="password" Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password"/>
                        <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Login" Command="{Binding OnLoginCommand}" Style="{StaticResource Buttons}"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
            <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" 
                         Padding="12"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                         AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,1,1">

                <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color ="#80000000"/>

                <Label Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>

            </StackLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**View Model:**

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechsportiseApp.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using TechsportiseApp.API;
using TechsportiseApp.ViewModels;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace TechsportiseApp.ViewModels
{
    public class LoginViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public LoginViewModel()
        {
            OnLoginCommand = new Command(ExecuteOnLogin);
        }

        private bool _isBusy;
        public bool IsBusy
        {
            get { return _isBusy; }
            set
            {
                if (_isBusy == value)
                    return;

                _isBusy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsBusy");
            }
        }

        private string _email;
        public string Email
        {
            get { return _email; }
            set
            {
                if (_email == value)
                    return;

                _email = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Email");
            }
        }

        private bool _password;
        public bool Password
        {
            get { return _password; }
            set
            {
                if (_password == value)
                    return;

                _password = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }

        private async void ExecuteOnLogin()
        {
            //Validations here
            if (Email == "")
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "You must enter an Email address", "OK"));
                return;
            }
            else if (Password == "")
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "You must enter a Password", "OK"));
                return;
            }
            //We are good to go
            else
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = true);
                string APIServer = Application.Current.Properties["APIServer"].ToString();
                var client = new RestClient(APIServer);
                var request = new RestRequest("api/account/sign-in", Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                request.AddJsonBody(new
                                        {
                                            email = Email,
                                            password = Password
                                        }
                                    );

                var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;

                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => IsBusy = false);
                //Valid response
                if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
                {
                    var tokenobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(response.Content);
                    Application.Current.Properties["Token"] = tokenobject.Access_token;
                    string token = Application.Current.Properties["Token"].ToString();
                    App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

                }
                //Error response
                else
                {
                    var statuscode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                    var content = response.Content;
                    var exception = response.ErrorException;
                    var error = response.ErrorMessage;
                    var statusdesc = response.StatusDescription;

                    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "Your login has failed. Please check your details and try again.", "OK"));
                }
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public Command OnLoginCommand {get;}
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh dear what a schoolboy error... thanks will try that when I am back at my pc and let you know...

Comment: No, unfortunately that still doesn't work. Same problem. Stepping through I see it setting the IsBusy flag but the screen does not display the ActivityIndicator. Not in the simulator at least...

Comment: It seems there is something up with the binding as I have tried putting a test textbox on that form to display the IsBusy value and it just sits saying false throughout the process

Comment: I see that you are referring IsBusy property like `this.IsBusy = true;` on the page... It should not be something like `this.BindingContext.IsBusy = true;`?

Comment: Interestingly, this.BindingContext.IsBusy is not valid - Its like the OnLogin method isn't able to make use of the binding context?

Comment: Actually BindingContext is `object`. You should write like `(this.BindingContext as LoginViewModel).IsBusy = true;`... did you got the idea?

Comment: Tried that and still no luck :-/

Comment: Are you sure that the code you share is running well? Once there's no "IsBusy" in your page's code behind that code should not work. There something very weird with this scenario

Comment: Functionally, everything runs normally. 

I only recently tried to introduce the Activity Indicator. So the actual mechanism of logging in works just fine. I was doing this previously without using a viewmodel at all. I only introduced it as the samples I was finding to implement an Activity Indicator said I needed to do it through a VM.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154731/discussion-between-diego-rafael-souza-and-matthew-warr).

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE]**
Maybe you should separate responsibilities. Create a class called `ViewModelBase` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` like this:

```cs
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool isBusy;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets a value indicating whether this instance is busy.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value><c>true</c> if this instance is busy; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</value>
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref isBusy, value);
        }
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the property.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns><c>true</c>, if property was set, <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
    /// <param name="backingStore">Backing store.</param>
    /// <param name="value">Value.</param>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name.</param>
    /// <param name="onChanged">On changed.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The 1st type parameter.</typeparam>
    protected bool SetProperty<T>(
        ref T backingStore, T value,
        [CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "",
        Action onChanged = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(backingStore, value))
            return false;

        backingStore = value;
        onChanged?.Invoke();
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when property changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    /// <summary>
    /// Raises the property changed event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName">Property name.</param>
    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Then creates another class called `LoginViewModel` that extends from `ViewModelBase` like this:

```
public class LoginViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand LoginCommand { get; set; }

    #region Properties
    private string _email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return _email; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _email, value); }
    }

    private string _password;

    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _password, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    public LoginViewModel()
    {
        LoginCommand = new Command(Login);
    }

    public string CleanResponse(string reason)
    {
        var str = reason;
        var charsToRemove = new string[] { "[", "]", "{", "}", "\"" };
        foreach (var c in charsToRemove)
        {
            str = str.Replace(c, string.Empty);
        }

        return str;
    }

    private async void Login()
    {
       //Validations here
        if (Email == "")
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "You must enter an Email address", "OK");
            return;
        }
        else if (Password == "")
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Validation Error", "You must enter a Password", "OK");
            return;
        }
        //We are good to go
        else
        {
            IsBusy = true;
            string APIServer = Application.Current.Properties["APIServer"].ToString();
            var client = new RestClient(APIServer);
            var request = new RestRequest("api/account/sign-in", Method.POST);
            request.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            request.AddJsonBody(new
                                    {
                                        email = Email,
                                        password = Password                                        }
                                );

            var response = client.Execute(request) as RestResponse;

            IsBusy = false;
            //Valid response
            if (response.StatusCode.ToString() == "OK")
            {
                var tokenobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TokenModel>(response.Content);
                Application.Current.Properties["Token"] = tokenobject.Access_token;
                string token = Application.Current.Properties["Token"].ToString();
                App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

            }
            //Error response
            else
            {
                var statuscode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
                var content = response.Content;
                var exception = response.ErrorException;
                var error = response.ErrorMessage;
                var statusdesc = response.StatusDescription;

                await DisplayAlert("Login Failed", "Your login has failed. Please check your details and try again.", "OK");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And your view like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="TechsportiseApp.Views.Login">
<ContentPage.Padding>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"
                iOS="20, 40, 20, 20"
                Android="20, 20, 20, 20"
                WinPhone="20, 20, 20, 20" />
</ContentPage.Padding>
<ContentPage.Content>
    <AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 Orientation="Vertical"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1">

                    <ScrollView  Orientation = "Vertical" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                 Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Image Source = "splash.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" />          
                            <Label Text="Race Director"
                            FontAttributes="Bold"
                            FontSize="Large"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            <Label Text="by Techsportise"
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            <BoxView HeightRequest="20" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                            <Entry x:Name="email" Text="{Binding Email}" Placeholder="Email address"/>
                            <Entry x:Name="password" Text="{Binding Password}" IsPassword="true" Placeholder="Password"/>
                            <Button x:Name="loginButton" Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Style="{StaticResource Buttons}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ScrollView>
            </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" Padding="12"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
             AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1">

            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Color ="#80000000"/>

            <Label Text="Loading..." HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="White"/>

        </StackLayout>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

```cs
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TechsportiseApp.Views;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using TechsportiseApp.API;
using TechsportiseApp.ViewModels;
using TechsportiseApp.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TechsportiseApp.Views
{
    public partial class Login : ContentPage
    {
        LoginViewModel viewModel;
        public Login ()
        {
            BindingContext = viewModel = new LoginPageViewModel();
            InitializeComponent ();
            ToolbarItems.Add(new ToolbarItem("New", "addperson.png", async () =>
            {
                 await Navigation.PushAsync(new Register());
            }));

         }
    }
}
```

I have tried this solution and it works perfectly...

Comment: No this isn't doing it. I think it is because I am trying to set a viewmodel property from code-behind. From what I am reading this isn't possible, but I also fail to see how it can be possible to implement the Activity Indicator at al if thats true! Very confused.

Comment: Maybe you should separate responsibilities. Create a class called `ViewModelBase` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` then creates another class called `LoginViewModel` that extends from ViewModelBase. Please read the update

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that last night too and no joy. There must be something fundamentally wrong with something I'm doing. Going to go back to the drawing board on the view.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but maybe this can help someone.  I too had problems with the ActivityIndicator not showing.

Here's some things I did to get it working.
On my ContentPage, it contained a ContentPage.Content element.  After removing this tag, it started working with the code below.

Binding property on my codebehind:

```
public partial class Login : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _busy = true;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool Busy
    {
        get { return _busy; }
        set
        {
            _busy = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Busy");
        }
    }

    private bool NotBusy => !Busy;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
        Busy = false;
    }

    private async void BtnLogin_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Busy = true;

        await Task.Delay(120); // gives UI a chance to show the spinner
        // do async login here
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var ct = cts.Token;
        var response = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => YourAuthenticationClass.YourLoginMethod(txtUserId.Text, txtPassword.Text).Result, ct);
        // check response, handle accordingly
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("RaisePropertyChanged('" + propName + "')");
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

ContentPage Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MyApp.Login">
<StackLayout Margin="10,10,10,0">
    <Image Source="mylogo.png"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Image>
    <Entry x:Name="txtUserId"
            Placeholder="Login Id"></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="txtPassword"
            Placeholder="Password"
            IsPassword="True">
    </Entry>
    <Button Text="Login"
        Clicked="BtnLogin_OnClicked"
        IsEnabled="{Binding NotBusy}"></Button>
    <ActivityIndicator
                    IsRunning="{Binding Busy}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding Busy}"
                    IsEnabled="True"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,-1,-1"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center">
        <ActivityIndicator.WidthRequest>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                <On Platform="Android">100</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ActivityIndicator.WidthRequest>
        <ActivityIndicator.Color>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                <On Platform="Android">#ff0000</On>
            </OnPlatform>
        </ActivityIndicator.Color>
    </ActivityIndicator>
</StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```